# how to set chain parameter in X509_STORE_CTX_init?

Tags: objective-c, openssl, certificate, verification

I am trying to use openssl for certificate chain verification using X509_verify_cert. I am getting all certificates- root certificate, intermediate certificate and child certificate which actually needs to be verified.
Using openssl I am able to convert certificate in X509 format.

```
X509_STORE_CTX *ctx;
ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
X509_STORE *store = X509_STORE_new();
X509_STORE_CTX_init(ctx, store, certificateX509, ?);

int status = X509_verify_cert(ctx);
```

while reading documentation about X509_STORE_CTX_init and X509_verify_cert, we need to pass certificate chain at ? in the code. In the documentation, X509_STORE_CTX_init method is defined like this:

```
int X509_STORE_CTX_init(X509_STORE_CTX *ctx, X509_STORE *store,
                        X509 *x509, STACK_OF(X509) *chain);
# define STACK_OF(type) struct stack_st_##type
```

How to pass certificate chain if I have all certificates in X509 format?
Any code snippet may help more.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:-

```
STACK_OF(X509) *chain = sk_X509_new_null();
sk_X509_push(chain, x509);
X509_STORE_CTX_init(x509_ctx, x509_trusted, x509, chain);
sk_X509_pop_free(obj->chain, X509_free);
```